# Calculating `a-b` for a large amount of rows extremely slow - can it be improved?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with the columns

`replication rank timestep duration`

After some subsetting there are `30 * 64 * 500` rows with `duration` info.

For every `replication` I want to calculate the absolute difference in
`duration` to all others (doing this for every timestep of every rank), thus
having `30C2 * 64 * 500` comparisons (because I'm doing `abs(a-b)`,
`replication1 - replication2` is the same as `replication2 - replication1`).

I have the code to do it, but it's extremely slow. I was wondering if there's
anyway to improve it.

```
my_diff <- function (df, X, Y)
{
    dfX <- df[df$replication == X,];
    dfY <- df[df$replication == Y,];

    diff <- dfX$duration - dfY$duration;

    dfdistanceXY <- data.frame(
        X = X,
        Y = Y,
        rank = dfX$rank,
        step = dfX$timestep,
        diffpositive = ifelse((diff)>0, TRUE, FALSE),
        diff = abs(diff));

    dfdistanceXY;
}
# Fast
dfkdiff <- dfk[with(dfk, order(replication, rank, timestep)),]
dfkdiff <- subset(dfkdiff, file == "none")
a <- min(unique(dfkdiff$replication))
b <- max(unique(dfkdiff$replication))
res = data.frame();
# Slow!
# file == "none" has odd numbers for $replication
for (i in seq(a, b, 2)) {
  if (i + 2 <= b) {
    for (j in seq(i + 2, b, 2)) {
      res <- rbind (res, my_diff(dfkdiff, i, j), check.names=F);
    }
  }
}
head(res);
```

Comment: You are growing your `res`, which is a big no-no. Preallocate it and watch it fly. Consider reading the [R inferno](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf) with a few more tricks. Finding bottle necks is usually done using [profiling](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Profiling.html).

Comment: Using a vectorized solution is probably even faster than pre-allocation. See e.g. [this tutorial](http://stcorp.nl/R_course/tutorial_control_flow.html) I wrote.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik I got it working now, thanks. If you want to add an answer with your suggestion I'll accept it.